# Moving gameObject with parent to face another gameObject

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have GameObject A, B, C. B is a child of A. B and C are cubes with one side highlighted.

I want to move and rotate B and his parent A to stick highlighted side of B to highlighted side of C object.

How to do this?

Comment: Can you show us code you tried yourself?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you only wanted to change A's value so that B location remain intact relative to A.

The simple solution would be to create a dummy object that is a child of C (so that its transform is relative to C), set it to the correct position and rotation you want A to be (where highlighted sides stick), then on runtime you could always move A into that location by setting its position and rotation to be the same as dummy's. Since dummy's transform is relative to C, no matter how you alter C's transform, dummy will always stay in correct location and gives you the correct values for A.

Another solution would be by Math. However, I think using complicated calculation functions will be not so efficient (both for the computer and your head lol). Using a dummy object would be better since Unity does the Math for you and it doesn't involve additional computation though. But perhaps it would be something like this:

```
public Transform a;
public Transform b;
public Transform c;

public Vector3 b_hl_dir; // highlight direction (e.g. right side would be {1,0,0} and back side would be {0,0,-1})
public Vector3 c_hl_dir;

public float width; // cube's width, assuming b and c has the same width.

public void RelocateA(){
    // #1. Calculate correct position for B
    Vector3 b_pos = c.position + c.rotation * c_hl_dir * width;
    Quaternion b_rot = Quaternion.LookRotation(c.position - b_pos, (Mathf.Abs(Vector3.Dot(c_hl_dir, Vector3.up)) < 1f) ? c.up : c.right) * Quaternion.FromToRotation(b_hl_dir, Vector3.forward);

    // #2. Relocate A according to B's correct position
    a.rotation = b_rot * Quaternion.Inverse(b.localRotation);
    a.position += b_pos - b.position;
}
```